# Run a Javascript code on an inactive browser tab every n hours

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, web-worker

I need to run a piece of Javascript code on a web page every 24 hours. I wrapped that code inside setInterval. That works, when the tab is active. However, when I come back after 24 hours I don't see it working. From my research on the internet, it appears that scripts on inactive tabs are de-prioritized by browsers. I see solutions based on Web Workers. Are there simpler alternate solutions to this problem?

Comment: Does the job need to precisely run every 24 hours?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: What does that js do? Does it really have to be done from that page? Could the same action be done by a browser extension (that gets loaded on all pages)? To not have timeouts throttled you need to keep the document active, meaning the CPU will have to work, even if it's for nothing 23h59 per days. That's not great for your hardware nor for the planet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I have a solution to my problem in question. I used "visibilityState" event to detect when an inactive tab is clicked, I also had a window scope variable that I used to record the last time when my script had executed(window.globalVar.lastProfileTime). Using both, I introduced this logic:

```html
const lastProfileTime = window.globalVar.lastProfileTime;
if((document.visibilityState === 'visible') &&
    ((typeof(lastProfileTime) === 'undefined') || 
    ((currentTime - lastProfileTime)  >  86400000))) { 
    // do something
}
```

This way, whenever user brings the browser tab into view, the visibilityState eventlistener triggers, and based on the 24hour check executes the piece of code I need. This way no timers required.